# how can I create iOS build file for react-native application?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I want to know if there is way for me to package iOS application, without paying for apple developer account in a file that I can send to other like the .apk for android.
I have worked in native android but I am new to the iOS, I have looked into the archive and .ipa file but they all require apple developer subscription or am I wrong?

is there a way for me to get a file for my react-native application that I will be able send to other iPhones so that It can be installed and run on those devices?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not the case with ios, you need to get an apple developer account and publish it as a test application there.

Comment: Choose your target device and build configuration (such as "Release" and "any iOS devices") in Xcode.
To create an archive of your application, select Product > Archive from the menu.
Once the build has been archived, it can be submitted to the App Store or distributed for testing.

Comment: https://youtu.be/fXeDe9tafG8?si=WooiHTmG7d6VTA-V and https://youtu.be/O5K0c6_xScw?si=Se9HFF0Lh3gL5AZJ 
You can view the two videos I shared, which guide you through the installation react native ios to xcode and xcode to apple app store process step-by-step so you can comprehend everything.